# Print stdout and stderr on the screen and also redirect each of them to a different file

Tags: linux, shell

I can do

```
$./a.out 1>stdout_file 2>stderr_file
```

But then i dont see anything on the screen. Or I can do

```
$./a.out | tee log.log
```

But then stdout and stderr goes to the same file.

How can I achieve both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? (I assume you're using bash as you're on Linux, not sure about other shells):

```
./a.out 1> >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log)
```

Comment: Note that this isn't completely without side effects: Ordering is no longer guaranteed (you can have a program print line-A to stderr followed by line-B to stdout, f/e, but have the stdout line actually reach the console first).

Comment: Can you elaborate how it works?

Comment: @drdot, the syntax in question is process substitution, discussed in detail at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst